# Changing Column Data Type Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, nba-api

I'm working on an NBA Project and I am using an API to get data from Basketball Reference. The data type "SEASONS" with the dataframe shown below is as a date time object and I want to change it to a String but I'm unable to. What Am i doing wrong? Code is below.
[Data Frame with Seasons column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fLo6.png)

```
player["SEASON"]=player["SEASON"].values.astype('str')
line_graph = px.bar(data_frame=player, x='SEASON', y="PTS")
```

despite doing this my graph still looks like this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLeJE.png) showing it may be in a date time format. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Don't include `.values`.  Just `player["SEASON"]=player["SEASON"].astype(str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SEASON column is a pandas datetime object, you can use the [.dt.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) method:

```
player["SEASON"]=player["SEASON"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
line_graph = px.bar(data_frame=player, x='SEASON', y="PTS")
```